# Why Linux inside KVM gets busy after I put the host to suspend-to-ram?

Tags: linux, kvm, suspend

I run another Linux instance inside KVM on my laptop.

When I suspend-to-ram the laptop and wake it up again, the guest Linux starts consuming 100% CPU for some time (maybe proportional to the sleep time) and becomes completely irresponsive. After it finally unstucks itself, I see `BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s`.

Why does it happen? How do I prevent this?

**Note:** The question is not about pausing (suspeding) the VM or guest system. It is about the disruption caused by *host's* suspend-to-ram.

Comment: Already noticed such behavior with a WinXP KVM Guest. So I guess this is more a KVM host issue. I am also interested in this answer.

Comment: Maybe this thing is related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1174654

Answer (score 0):

The error can be ignored. This is due to the fact that the virtual CPU thinks it has missed some time, i.e. has been locked up, while in fact it was suspended and couldn't get scheduled while unsuspending.

As for the load, it's normal, reading a few GB of data into RAM, mapping the RAM to the VM's page offset takes loads of CPU and disk operations.

Comment: Why do it need to `read a few GB into RAW`? It's not hibernation, it's suspend-to-ram. Does `mapping the RAM to VM's page offset` take a minute of 100% CPU time and proportional to the sleep time? The error is not to be ignored (it annoys, as I have to wait before accessing VM again). Actually `BUG: soft lockup` occurs not every time, but the freeze occurs always.

Comment: Working with gigabytes of data takes time. You can't break the laws of physics. If you don't like it, don't suspend or hybernate your laptop.

Comment: What gigabytes of data? It it clear why hibernation needs to work with gigabytes of data, but why the suspension?

Comment: Because the VM pauses, and unpausing means reading and remapping the entire memdump into RAM again.

Comment: Why should VM pause? I think it does not. I have just tried short suspend-to-raw of the host - no [visible] VM hang. The time for which it is busy after resuming is proportional to the time I keep computer suspended.

Comment: That sounds strange to me. Get into the code, or ask the developers on the qemu mailing list

Comment: Maybe it's not Qemu's wrong, but Linux's wrong for reacting badly to clock jump?

Comment: All you get in reaction to the clock jump will be the CPU error you posted earlier. In any case, if there's a known bug, the folks in the qemu list will know